# Newton's 1st law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity

***If all of a sudden the gravitational force and gravity disappears then the planets would still continue to rotate and revolve ? Give reason***

Comment: No they wouldn't. They would continue going in the direction they were going , TANGENTIALLY, and not go around in circles. They would go in a straight line in the direction they were going at that point in time and space.  If you change the question to ask what will happen to their orbits, then maybe.  You need to know your physics a little better. Circular motion is not inertial mottion, only constant direction and constant speed, or at rest, is.

Comment: Please let us know what your own answer and effort is before asking for the solution

Answer (score 1):

Velocity is a vector quantity. It has magnitude as well as direction, so if suddenly all gravitational force disappeared then all planets will move tangentially. It can be proved by a simple experiment:

Tie a weight to a string and rotate it and suddenly cut that string without disturbing the system. It will move tangentially. In this experiment tension in that string represents gravitational force.